# Make Cairo Dock update like launcher does

Tags: 12.10, cairo-dock

Is there anyway to make the Cairo Dock mirror the launcher? Such as showing programs when they're open?

Comment: What do you mean by mirror? Do you want to run the Unity launcher and Cairo simultaneouly or do you want it to replicate the launcher's behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the dock and choose Cairo-Dock > Configure.  In the "Behavior" group click on "Taskbar".  There you will find the option to "Show currently opened applications in the dock".  There are also a variety of other options there related to open application icons.

Answer (score -1):

This is in the advanced configuration.
In the simple configuration, just select "integrated" for the type of taskbar.